# Is there a decent technique for SSIS Derived Column date formatting?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I just had to write the most redonkulous expression in an SSIS Derived Column to get dates formatted like "01-JAN-2010".  It lookes like this:

[image]

There's got to be a better way...  isn't there?

Comment: +1 for using the work redonkulous haha

Answer (score 5):

Consider using a script component and then `Row.stringcol = Row.datecol.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")` to populate a new string column in the data flow.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use expressions, you could use this instead:

RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DAY(ASSIGNMENT_BEGIN_DATE), 2) + "-" + SUBSTRING("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC", (3 * MONTH(ASSIGNMENT_BEGIN_DATE)) - 2, 3) + (DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(ASSIGNMENT_BEGIN_DATE)

Didn't say it was better.  It's just different and shorter.  Use a Script as Cade suggested if you want better control.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, now I feel like a Donkey.  The easy solution is to make my Data Source a select statement in which I simply handle that column like this:

`SELECT to_char(assignment_begin_date, 'dd-MON-yyyy') assignment_begin_date FROM ...`

The RDBMS is Oracle, btw.

Then I don't need to do a derived column or a script.

I have self-administered a dope-slap for not thinking of it earlier.  Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: I assumed you were going out of SQL Server (which doesn't have a very easy way to do that particular format), and I had written a suggestion of formatting it on the way out, but then decided doing it in T-SQL was still too messy. I assume you aren't going into SQL Server, because then I would ask why you are formatting this date into text at all.

Comment: Thanks Cade, and sorry my buffoonery wasted your time.  It's going into a flat file, so that's why the unusual formatting is needed.

Comment: So not even going through SQL Server at all?

Comment: @Cade, the data may end up in a SQL Server db in another process, but this particular package is just extracting it from Oracle and putting it into a flat file on a file server.  Otherwise I'd just Select from Oracle and Insert into SQL Server in a Data Flow Task.